# Scrape part of <li> from <ul> class?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, stock

Tring to get "bullets" for each "li class mc" from "ul class mc-list" for my list of stocks from the [web](https://seekingalpha.com/dividends/dividend-news).

I'm new in Python and I would like to a bit automatize check for my stock portfolio.

I have a file (mystocks.txt) with tickers of stocks (one ticket per line).

Once a day I would like to check the SA [web](https://seekingalpha.com/dividends/dividend-news) if there was any news for any of my stock.

```
url = 'https://seekingalpha.com/dividends/dividend-news'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
for link in soup.find_all('li'):
...
```

The expected output is:

> if div.bullets contain ticker from "mystocks.txt" then a file named "ticket".txt should be created and contain "div.bullets" text.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the implementation below. I hope it will get you there:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://seekingalpha.com/dividends/dividend-news"

#following are the pseudo list of tickers you might wanna check against
for ticker in ['NWTUF','BSL','KRC']:
    res = requests.get(link,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

    for item in soup.select(".media-body"):
        #if there is no match, get rid of the content
        if ticker not in item.text:continue

        for elem in item.select(".bullets > ul > li, .bullets > ul > li > a"):
            print(elem.text)
        print("***"*20)
```

Comment: Hello,
thank you for help/advise, unfortunately, it doesnt work

import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    link = "https://seekingalpha.com/dividends/dividend-news"
    for ticker in ['NWTUF','BSL','KRC']:
... res = requests.get(link,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    res = requests.get(link,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Indentation is one of the most important and very basic thing in python programming that you should learn first. However, if you run the code as it is, you should not encounter any error. I checked it just now. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you can get away with  _.bullets li, .bullets a_  as well   +

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test it once I will be back to my PC on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

Small progress made (learning in progress), reading file line by line added, but it does not print divi record even if the ticket is on the page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://seekingalpha.com/dividends/dividend-news"
fileHandler = open ("tickers.txt", "r")

with open ("tickers.txt", "r") as fileHandler:
  for ticker in fileHandler:
    print(ticker.strip())
    res = requests.get(link,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

    for item in soup.select(".media-body"):
        #if there is no match, get rid of the content
        if ticker not in item.text:continue

        for elem in item.select(".bullets > ul > li, .bullets > ul > li > a"):
            print(elem.text)
        print("***"*20)

# Close Close
fileHandler.close()
```

Output looks like (tried all possible names):
rpi2:~$ ./divi.py
MAIN
TJX
NASDAQ:NWFL
Altria
Ralph Lauren